# target a form using button

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I want to create a clickable button which send me the user at the form section(at same page).

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    send me to the form
</button>
...
<form id="form1">
    <div class="form-group">
      ...
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But I didn't find any solution.
Is there any why to do it without rely on jquery/JS? If not then how to target the form?  [Here](https://codepen.io/falamiw/pen/WNQopRG) is my codepen in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

nest your button in the link tag this way:

```
<a href="#form-1"> 
  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    send me to the form
</button>
```